# Do we have scriptural reference on Ashta Bhairava incarnations?

Tags: scripture, reference-request, bhairava

Lord Shiva took the avatar of Kala Bhairava to kill the ego of Lord Brahma is the first Bhairava avatar of Shiva. Do we have reference to Ashta Bhairava stories in our texts?

Comment: I could only find the following reference which is remotely similair: “There was one demon by name Dahurāsuraṇ who got a boon that he could be killed only by a woman. Kālī was created by Śaktī to kill him. The wrath of Kālī killed the demon. After killing the demon, her wrath metamorphosed as a child. Kālī fed the child with her milk. Śiva made both Kālī and the child to merge with Him. From this merged form of Śiva, Bhairva appeared in his eight forms (aṣṭa Bhairava-s).” https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/lalitha-sahasranamam-782-785

Comment: Well I later realised that the info my answer is giving is trivial. For e.g we can get it from Wiki too.. So my answer is not useful at all.. so deleted it..

Comment: @Rickross - Thing as Bhairava, the 8 forms, seems to have happened in Tamil Nadu around Thanjavur-Nagapattinam districts. Because I had been there in last 3 months, and found history of it in temples.